# Codificar correctamnte una url en Android Java

Tags: java, android

Estoy intentando de codificar correctamente una dirección web, solicitada al usuario mediante un EditText, es decir que los carácteres esten escapados correctamente como especifica [aquí](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), preseverando su estructura y tipo de codificación adecuada en cada segmento.

Los espacios en los directorios representados con ˋ%20ˋ y la entrada de parametros, despues del ˋ?ˋ los espacios sean ˋ+ˋ

Es decir que si el usurio separa parte de la url con espacios se codifiqu correctamnte

Ejemplo:

[http://miestanteria.es/mi%20coleccion/libros.php?año=2018&autor=mi+autor+preferido](http://miestanteria.es/mi%20coleccion/libros.php?a%C3%B1o=2018&autor=mi+autor+preferido)

Comment: El usuario va ingresar la URL? no entendi eso

Comment: Si la dirección web es entrada con una EditText

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma sería limpiando la cadena por partes, es decir primero lo que esta antes del ? y luego la otra parte:

Ejemplo:

```
String urlText = "http://miestanteria.es/mi coleccion/libros.php?año=2018&autor=mi autor preferido";
    String urlBase = urlText.split("\\?")[0];
    String urlParameter= urlText.split("\\?")[1];
    String urlLimpia = urlBase.replace(" ","%20")+"?"+urlParameter.replace(" ","+");
    Log.i("*****",urlLimpia);
```